# Creating a history back link and make use of my existing link component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-component

I have a certain generic link component (an atom, I am using Atomic design for structuring my React app), which either returns just a `<span>` with a Title and arrow icon or when it does have a `url` it returns a react-router-dom `<Link>`.

I am using react-router-dom v5.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Arrow} from 'app/icons';

import { Props } from './MyLink.types';

const MyLink = ({ variant = 'iconRight', text, url }: Props) => {
  const renderLinkBody = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span css={styles.label}>{text}</span>
        <Arrow />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return url !== undefined ? (
    <Link to={url} title={text} >
      {renderLinkBody()}
    </Link>
  ) : (
    <span>{renderLinkBody()}</span>
  );
};

export default MyLink;
```

Now I want to use this component for creating a Back button (similar behaviour as the browser back button).

Is it a clean approach passing an onClick prop (function) from parent to child, something like:

```
const history = useHistory();

<MyLink text="My title" variant="iconLeft" onClick={history.goBack} />
```

and then adjust MyLink component a bit:

```
 return url !== undefined || onClick ? (
    <Link to={url} title={text} onClick={onClick} >
      {renderLinkBody()}
    </Link>
  ) : (
    <span>{renderLinkBody()}</span>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this approach isn't bad. When attaching an `onClick` handler to the `Link` component you will likely need to prevent the default link behavior from occurring. You will also need to provide a valid `to` prop to the `Link` component when using a click handler.

Example:

```
const MyLink = ({ variant = "iconRight", onClick, text, url }) => {
  const clickHandler = e => {
    if (onClick) {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick();
    }
  };

  const renderLinkBody = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <span css={styles.label}>{text}</span>
        <Arrow />
      </>
    );
  };

  return url !== undefined || onClick ? (
    <Link to={url || "/"} title={text} onClick={clickHandler} >
      {renderLinkBody()}
    </Link>
  ) : (
    <span>{renderLinkBody()}</span>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-creating-a-history-back-link-and-make-use-of-my-existing-link-component]

Because of the issue with the `onClick` and the `Link` action, you may want to make the "back" navigation a button instead, and refactor `MyLink` to conditionally render the button, the link, or the span, depending on needs.